# Why does my basement smell like my drop-ceiling tiles?

Tags: basement, ceiling, smell

So I recently refinished my basement.  In the process, I replaced the entire drop ceiling with new tiles.  I finished that a couple of months ago.

I recall the distinct smell of the dust that these tiles create when handled or when I would drill holes in them.  I am now occasionally smelling that same dust in my basement.  Some days its there, others its not.

Nothing is disturbing the tiles (no, there aren't animals in the ceiling) and I haven't been moving them around for any reason.  They are just sitting there.

What could cause the tiles to emit dust and create that smell?  How do I get rid of it?

Comment: ventilate and clean the basement until the remaining dust is gone.

Comment: @ratchetfreak:  I did that. I removed all the carpet and old ceiling, then I installed the new ceiling, then cleaned the entire basement again, painted the walls, cleaned, installed floor, cleaned.  It's clean.  As I mentioned, the smell is not constant - it's occasional.

Comment: It will dissipate in short order.

Comment: @Jack:  the ceiling has been installed for 3 months, and the rest of the basement has been finished for over 1 month.  Seems like "short order" is over.  but perhaps I'm impatient.

Comment: Have you moved in down there and start using the place as normal? The one thing to consider is that the ceiling is a lot of area so you have a lot of material up in place that will take a while for it all to mellow out so to speak. Once you start using it after a time other smells will be introduced and it should negate the ceiling tile smell I would imagine.

Comment: We aren't using it "as normal" yet, no.  But I am down there almost daily, mostly painting trim and measuring for furniture and such.  
I supposed I'll just wait.  Thanks for the comments everyone.

Comment: The ceiling tiles will loose their smell over time until you will hardly notice them. When I finished my basement it took many months to get rid of the smell. You have to keep venting the area to reduce the smell. That  smell is from the tiles " out-gassing". which slowly reduces over time.

Comment: Ahh that new car smell oh I mean ceiling tile, it will dissipate with time just like a car. Since this is a basement and you walk above there may still be some rubbing going on that causes the edges to further outgas as others have said it will go away with time I think I have read some appliances on this site taking 6 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as new homes and new cars smell new for years, your basement will smell new until enough activity and ventilation have occurred. I lined part of my basement workshop with OSB two years ago and I still smell it when I walk down there.

I suggest time and air. Worst-case scenario you replace the tiles, but I doubt it'll come to that.

Comment: Any idea what is being 'outgassed' from these tiles which causes the smell?

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm not much of a chemist.